# Javascript in stand alone Flash / Flash lite app

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can a stand alone flash / flashlite app invoke javascript functions using externalinterface or any other interfacing feature in actionscript ?

thanks
kunal

Comment: I don't really understand, if the flash is standalone, which environment would it be calling the javascript in? Normally you call javascript in application that holds the flash (usually a browser). where would these javascripts be located?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it using:

```
ExternalInterface.call("javaScriptFunction", "parameter", "parameter");
```

[Here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Charlie boy has pointed out my concern as well. Using ExternalInterface, Javascript is invoked in the container (eg, the web browser) that also runs flash.

In our case, what I am trying to do is have a standalone actionscript utility on a client (eg, could be a mobile phone) render HTML/CSS/JS that is fetched from a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

you can always play with anonymous functions as well if you dont have direct access to the container:

[anonymous function calling](http://www.themorphicgroup.com/blog/2008/06/05/anonymous-functions-from-externalinterface/)